# Calculating lat/long in NAD 83 and NAD 27 using arcpy or modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

I have four double columns for lat/long with NAD 83 and NAD 27.  The native projection of the data is in NAD 83, but the client want's the attributes filled out for NAD 27 as well.  I want to calculate these fields with a script before I sent out to a client.  I can use the field calculator to calculate this:

```
def find(shape):  
  point = shape.getPart(0)  
  return point.Y
```

`find(!Shape!)`

This works for the native projection of the data.  Is there a way to change the projection to NAD 27 and calculate the other fields in it?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you'll have to project your feature class to determine the values. Check the code below, which creates a NAD27 spatial reference, projects, uses a dictionary to store the desired data, and then updates the feature class with the Xs and Ys. The script assumes there is a unique ID field for your feature class, as well as a NAD27 X and a NAD27 Y field (the fields you wish to populate). Let me know if you have any questions! I shall caveat the code by saying it's not fully tested.

```
#---Local variables

#In feature class
inFC = r"C:\Test\Test.gdb\testInput"
#Fields
uidFld = "UNIQUEID"
nad27Xfld = "NAD27_X"
nad27Yfld = "NAD27_Y"

workspace = r"C:\temp\Workspace.gdb"

#---End locals

from arcpy import *
import os

#Create Nad 27 spatial reference object
print "creating spatial reference object"
SR83 = Describe (inFC).spatialReference.name
SR27 = SpatialReference (SR83.replace ("1983", "1927")
                         .replace ("_", " "))

#X and Y value dictionaries
Xdi = {}
Ydi = {}

#Project
print "projecting"
projectedFC = os.path.join (workspace, "tempProjected")
Project_management (inFC, projectedFC, SR27)

#Iterate Xs and Ys
print "determining XYs"
cursor = da.SearchCursor (projectedFC, [uidFld, "SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y"])
for row in cursor:
    Xdi [row[0]] = row[1]
    Ydi [row[0]] = row[2]
del cursor

#Update NAD 27 X any Y field
print "updating XYs"
cursor = da.UpdateCursor (inFC, [uidFld, nad27Xfld, nad27Yfld])
for row in cursor:
    row[1] = Xdi[row[0]]
    row[2] = Ydi[row[0]]
    cursor.updateRow (row)
del cursor

#Delete projected FC
Delete_management (projectedFC)

print "done"
```